# Trying to send an EOF signal (Ctrl+D) signal using Python via Popen()

Tags: python-2.7, posix, popen, eof

I'm trying to get Python to send the `EOF` signal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) via `Popen()`. Unfortunately, I can't find any kind of reference for `Popen()` signals on *nix-like systems. Does anyone here know how to send an `EOF` signal like this? Also, is there any reference of acceptable signals to be sent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EOF` isn't really a signal that you can raise, it's a per-channel exceptional condition. (Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to signal end of interactive input is actually a function of the terminal driver. When you press this key combination at the beginning of a new line, the terminal driver tells the OS kernel that there's no further input available on the input stream.)

Generally, the correct way to signal `EOF` on a pipe is to close the write channel. Assuming that you created the Popen object with `stdin=PIPE`, it looks like you should be able to do this.